# JS merge Array of the Maps to a single Map

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

I have a structure of

```
Array(4) [Map(1),Map(1),Map(1),Map(1)]
```

All keys are different there.
I am trying find the common way to merge it in one Map.

I know the way for two Maps:

```
let merged = new Map([...first, ...second])
```

But for this solution I need more common way.

Comment: reduce might be a way?

Comment: @cmgchess it seems flatMap is a more short way, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const arr = [
  new Map([[1, 2]]),
  new Map([[3, 4]]),
];

const merged = arr.flatMap(e => [...e])

console.log(merged)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.map` each map to its entries, then flatten the array of arrays of entries to just a single array of entries, then turn that into a Map.

```js
const arr = [
  new Map([[1, 2]]),
  new Map([[3, 4]]),
];

const merged = new Map(
  arr.map(
    map => [...map]
  ).flat()
);
console.log([...merged]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to merge multiple `Map`.

```
maps.reduce((r, map) => new Map([...r, ...map]), new Map())
```

```js
const map1 = new Map();
map1.set('a', 1);
const map2 = new Map();
map2.set('b', 2);
const map3 = new Map();
map3.set('c', 3);

const maps = [map1, map2, map3],
      merged = maps.reduce((r, map) => new Map([...r, ...map]), new Map());
console.log([...merged]);
```